# Can you Make a Boolean value turn off/on automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, logic, conditional-statements

Okay I have declared a Key  CellX to boolean value True. In a sense as long as this value remains true my data will keep inserting in and If I turn it false it will stop at what ever count it was on. Now I have to Stop at when 400 orders have been inserted in data base and no more... can I actually apply a condition 
like 
Key CellX "True" 
if CellX ==400 then "False"
else 
 "True"

can we accomplish this... I am doing in C#.

I C most of you have given good logic.
little more CellX is declared in web.xml along with other keys such as CellA, B, C and A, B, are receiving data in DB so to stop it from reaching 400 I can manually change the CellX Boolean Value or How can I implement a condition which will make  my Boolean value to turn false when Cell A, B, C reach 400.

Comment: CellX is a boolean but you compare it like an integer?

Comment: I realize there's a language barrier, but it's _very_ difficult to understand exactly what you're asking.  Can you maybe write some code that expresses what you would want to accomplish but doesn't actually work (that is, shows the problem)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
myBool = (CellX == 400);
```

However, in your post you refer to CellX as both a boolean and as something that can be compared to an integer value of 400.  A given variable can be boolean or an integer.

If CellX is your boolean, instead do something like:

```
CellX = (myLoopCounter == 400);
```

The syntax

```
myBool = (myLoopCounter == 400);
```

evaluates like this:

- Evaluate whether myLoopCounter is exactly 400 (true, or false)
- Assign the result of the previous step to myBool

Answer (score 1):

A variable can't be dynamically evaluated like that (at least not in the way I think you're looking for, things like `Func` notwithstanding).  But you can create it as a read-only property on the class which would be evaluated each time (since a property is mainly a syntactically different form of a method call):

```
private bool LimitReached
{
    get
    {
        return (CellX == 400);
    }
}
```

So if you keep checking the value of `LimitReached` over and over, it should potentially change if the value of `CellX` is also changing.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
int Counter = 1;
bool Continue = true;
while(Continue)
{
    // Insert one row
    if (Counter == 400)
        Continue = false;
    Counter++;
}
```

This can also be written:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
{
    // insert one row
}
```

Comment: I'd caution against using a variable with the same name as a keyword.